# find() Vs $(selector)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a **table structure** where I have to **find table cells** with **some specific Classes**

the query goes like this:

```
$('#attendance-data > table > tbody > tr > td.activeCell');
```

The reason i am using child combinator selector (' > ') is because i have nested table within table cells.

i know i can also write this query as:

```
$('#attendance-data').find('td.activeCell');
```

**It** gives the same output as the above query and is **shorter** but which **one is more optimised**??

Comment: The second one would grab the elements from the nested level too..

Comment: Why use such a specific selector in your first example. I'm quite sure `$('#attendance-data td.activeCell');` would achieve the same result, but of course we would need to see some HTML to be 100% sure.

Comment: The second one is probably more "optimized", because it doesn't have to specifically check levels of children. But it does something totally different than the first

Comment: Test it. That's what [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com) is for. [Check this one out](http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-context-selector).

Comment: @Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy - If i dont have to bother about the nested levels i would change my query to $('attendance-data td.activeCell') but then again which one is more optimised $('attendance-data td.activeCell')  vs $('attendance-data').find('td.activeCell')...how are these two processed??

Comment: It's probably **much** more important to optimize the work you do **after** the selector finds the `<td>` elements.  Modern browsers have very high-performance selector engines, so unless you're doing that lookup extremely frequently it's not worth worrying about.